# dart-pdf Flutter pdf Center and fullscreen preview documents with only one page

Tags: flutter, dart-pdf

I'm using Flutter pdf and Printing to create and preview Pdf's documents. In my case, these documents have only one page each so, I want them to show at center in a fullscreen default mode.

I have notice that if I double tap a page, this one gets centered in the screen and you can do a zoom-in.

How can I put my documents in that state by default? Without having to double tap them in first place.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:printing/printing.dart';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;

class PdfPage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: PdfPreview(
            previewPageMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
            useActions: false,
            build: (format) {
              final pdf = pw.Document();

              pdf.addPage(
                pw.Page(
                  build: (pw.Context context) => pw.Center(
                    child: pw.Text('Hello World!'),
                  ),
                ),
              );

              return pdf.save();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use **enableScrollToPage: true** to center the page on the screen when displayed.

```
   PdfPreview(
      enableScrollToPage: true,
      // Other properties...
    ),
```